# R seq: what is the exact value?

Tags: r, sum, decimal

Are there limitations to `seq`? I can not explain this:

```
x=seq(from=.008, to=.015, by=.001)
x
[1] 0.008 0.009 0.010 0.011 0.012 0.013 0.014 0.015
x[2]
[1] 0.009
x[x==0.009]
numeric(0)
x[x==.01]
[1] 0.01
```

What is the exact value of `x[2]`?
To my surprise:

```
(.008+.001)==.009
[1] FALSE
(.08+.01)==.09
[1] TRUE
```

How does R sum `0.008+.001` and what is the exact value?
As @joran pointed out, the question has already been answered.
In this case, the easiest solution is

```
x[round(x,3)==.009]
[1] 0.009
round(.008+.001,3)==.009
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: tks, @joran. Can (May/Should) I delete this question?

Comment: No need for that.